# Selenium click button with weird text (windows, chromedriver)

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make my bot click a purchase button, but it has some weird text that doesn't make my code work (I think that's why don't be mad if I'm wrong).

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYVFL.png)

Code that I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@text()="20 Bits"]').click()
```

I also tried by class but it doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `@` in front of `text()`.  There is a lot of white space around the text so you want to use `contains`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(),"20 Bits")]').click()
```

---

I would suggest using

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

.....
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"20 Bits")]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(“//button[@class=‘purchase bits flat no-cap’]”).click()
```